# Most efficient way call C# code from C code on Linux

Tags: c#, c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to call c# code in c code on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213288/whats-the-best-way-to-call-c-sharp-code-in-c-code-on-linux)

What's the most efficient way to call C# code from C code on Linux? I am now using sockets but wondering if it's the most efficient way. Has anyone tested about it?

Thanks.

Simon

Comment: what do you defined as efficient? What is the target machine which is running the C# code, or is it all on the same machine?

Comment: This post may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428267/calling-c-sharp-from-c

Comment: It's all on the same machine.